# Using decode to input 'Not a valid month' value as it is

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT CAST(LAST_DAY(to_timestamp(lpad(cast(NUMBER_COLUMN as varchar2(6)), 6, '0'), 'MMYYYY')) AS TIMESTAMP) AS NUMBER_COLUMN_ALIAS FROM TAB1 T1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT TIMESTAMP_COLUMN FROM 
                     (SELECT TIMESTAMP_COLUMN FROM TAB2)
                     WHERE TIMESTAMP_COLUMN=CAST(LAST_DAY(to_timestamp(lpad(cast(NUMBER_COLUMN as   varchar2(6)), 6, '0'), 'MMYYYY')) AS TIMESTAMP));
```

I have two data columns--one is NUMBER_COLUMN and one is TIMESTAMP_COLUMN. I need to convert NUMBER_COLUMN to TIMESTAMP_COLUMN format and match their records.

The above query works but the thing is there are some bad data values in my NUMBER_COLUMN which will return an error of 'not a valid month'.
My query only works with number values such as 52002,41995,122016 which will be converted into something like 5/31/2002, 4/31/1995, 12/31/2016 respectively.

Now there are these 'bad' data values such as 0, 10000, 131994,421996,731989 and many more. 
I want the query to return the bad data value as it is so I don't have to convert them, else use `CAST(LAST_DAY(to_timestamp(lpad(cast(NUMBER_COLUMN as varchar2(6)), 6, '0'), 'MMYYYY'))`
to convert the good data values.

I could manually list out all the 'bad' values in the decode function but is there an easier way to trap them?

I am running out of ideas. 
Thanks

Comment: Why not just make your own function where you try to convert and if it fails, trap the "not a valid month" exception and return the original value?

Comment: @craig I need to fetch them into a cursor and use bulk load later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   number_column,
         case   when number_column between 10000 and 129999 
                     and mod(number_column,10000) between 1900 and 2100 
                then 'good format' 
                else 'bad format'
         end result
from
    (select 52002 number_column from dual union all
     select 41995 number_column from dual union all
     select 122016 number_column from dual union all
     select 0 number_column from dual union all
     select 10000 number_column from dual union all
     select 131994 number_column from dual union all
     select 421996 number_column from dual union all
     select 731989 number_column from dual )



 ╔════════╦═════════════╗
 ║  52002 ║ good format ║
 ║  41995 ║ good format ║
 ║ 122016 ║ good format ║
 ║      0 ║ bad format  ║
 ║  10000 ║ bad format  ║
 ║ 131994 ║ bad format  ║
 ║ 421996 ║ bad format  ║
 ║ 731989 ║ bad format  ║
 ╚════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: is it possible to replace then 'good format' with then CAST(LAST_DAY(to_timestamp(lpad(cast(NUMBER_COLUMN as varchar2(6)), 6, '0'), 'MMYYYY'))? I need to display the converted data.

Comment: Need a little more direction.  You can't mix datatypes in a single result column - so you can't have a single result column where 'good' records are TIMESTAMP and 'bad' records are NUMBER.  You could have a VARCHAR2 result column, and return 'good' records as a formatted timestamp string and 'bad' formatted as just a simple number; or both (1) a GOOD_FORMAT TIMESTAMP column where good vals are returned and bad vals are NULL plus (2) a BAD_FORMAT NUMBER column where good vals are NULL and bad vals are a NUMBER.  The "right" answer depends on what you plan to do with these computed results.